# VS2010 - Project Macro Variables in Start Options Command Line Arguments

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

In a projects settings, on the Debug tab, is there a way to use to use the project macro variables in the command line arguments box?

I know you can't use them directly because they don't get expanded but is there a clever solution to this?

EDIT: I'm using a C# project.

Comment: If you want this supported, I suggested it to the VS team, you can vote for it at: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/6350738-support-for-macros-in-debugging-command-line-argum

Comment: This feature is now supported for C# **.NET Core** console apps.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/41961568/2832598

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is supported [*but not for C# projects*].

Silly example I tried: Command Arguments = `$(CharacterSet)`.  Got `"Unicode"` at runtime for `argv[1]` inside `main()`.

Select "Command Arguments", click on the dropdown arrow, Edit.  Click Macros to see what macros are available.

Comment: I should have indicated that I am developing a C# app.

Comment: Yes, you should have.  The C# IDE doesn't support this.  A possible workaround is a post-build event that writes a file that you read in your program.  Like `echo $(ProjectName) > "$(TargetDir)cmdargs.txt`